# xml parsing terminated inexplicably

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I have a file filled with sentences wrapped in wellformed XML (xmllint and tidylib says so).
So the xml looks like this:

```
<a id="100" attr1="text" attr1="text" attr1="text">
<tagname id="1">
This is my sentence.
</tagname>
</a>
<a id="101" attr1="text" attr1="text" attr1="text">
<tagname id="1">
This is my sentence.
</tagname>
</a>
```

and so on.

I use the following code to extract the sentences with the attribute (in this case from id 1 to 85)

```
a1 = open(r"file.xml",'r')
a = a1.readlines()
a1.close()
soup = BeautifulSoup(str(a))
for i in range(1,85):
    a = soup.find('a', {'id': i})
    achild = a.find('tagname')
    tagnametext = achild.contents
    print tagnametext
```

everything prints nicely, until sentence 84, at which I receive the error:
achild = a.find('tagname')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

Each set of ... is generated with a for loop so the xml is all the same.
I've tried with different files with varying numbers of sentences. The id at which the error occurs also changes.
Is this a limitation of beautifulsoup?
That it can't scan past a certain number of lines?

Comment: What does id number 84 look like?

Answer (score 0):

It fails on the last line. It might be a file encoding issue, that the line contains some funny EOF character, or that the line isn't interpreted as a string. Can you print out the last line before it fails and see what type it is?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely `a = soup.find('a', {'id': i})` with `84` does not return what you expect. `find()` returns `None` if the tag is not found, thus explaining the `AttributeError`

Also, in your code, you seem to be BeautifulSouping a list (represented as a string).

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(str(a))
```

You're stringing a list, then souping the list, which is silly. How about soup the whole file and then loop through each a tag if it has an `id`?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
with open('file.xml', 'r') as myfile:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(myfile.read())
    for i in soup.find_all('a', id=True):
        print i.tagname.contents
```

Prints:

```
[u'\nThis is my sentence.\n']
[u'\nThis is my sentence.\n']
```

Comment: soup = BeautifulSoup(myfile.read()) crashes my python IDLE GUI. The file contains around 140,000 sentences

Comment: @waterling Probably not the best choice then.